# «С аккаунта» или «из аккаунта» — как правильно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, выбор-варианта

*С одного и того же аккаунта четверо пользователей не могут получить доступ к системе одновременно.*
Какой нужен предлог?

Comment: Уважаемые участники форума с хорошим чувством языка и знанием компьютерных технологий. Вы не могли бы сказать, как вы сами произносите  эту фразу. Ничего не доказывая, просто на слух. Мы же говорим: зайти с чужого компьютера на свою страницу. Не из чужого же! Точно так же можно сказать про аккаунт, как мне кажется. А вам?

Comment: Молчание. Ладно, оставлю эту тему. Хочу только сказать, что русский язык не копирует иноязычные предлоги, а приспособливает их перевод (в соответствии с их значениями) к своим традициям и особенностям. Не хотелось бы становиться КАЛЬКОЙ с английского языка даже в данном случае.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полагаю, что, будучи калькой с английского, корректно либо:

*С одним и тем же аккаунтом четверо пользователей не могут получить доступ к системе одновременно* (*Four users can't access the system with the same account*), если *аккаунт* используется в значении *учетные данные*;

либо

*Из-под одного и того же аккаунта четверо пользователей не могут получить доступ к системе одновременно* (*Four users can't access the system from under the same account*), если *аккаунт* используется в значении *профиль* пользователя.

Для краткости в обоих языках можно опустить *под*/*under*:

*Из одного и того же аккаунта четверо пользователей не могут получить доступ к системе одновременно* (*Four users can't access the system from the same account*).

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, можно ли эту ситуацию записать следующим образом (или я неверно ее понимаю):  Используя одну и ту же учетную запись, четверо пользователей не могут одновременно  войти в систему, то есть получить доступ к ней. Если это неверно, то как записать это с оборотом "используя"?

Comment: Так как участник не стал отвечать на мой комментарий, то я могу пока ПРЕДПОЛОЖИТЬ, что его ответ неверен. Использование предлогов  В, ИЗ, С    в русском языке имеет свои особенности по сравнению с англоязычным вариантом. К примеру, я могу сказать: войти в аккаунт, выйти из аккаунта, зайти  в какую-то базу или систему со своего аккаунта, но только не «из своего аккаунта». Вот некоторые примеры на тему: Как только с данного аккаунта делается еще одна авторизация, то все предыдущие обнуляются.

Comment: Или: При подключении нескольких баз (или нескольких входов в одну и ту же базу) с одного рабочего места  выдается одна лицензия. Поэтому хотелось бы услышать и ДРУГИЕ МНЕНИЯ по этому вопросу.

Comment: *С одним и тем же аккаунтом четверо пользователей не могут получить доступ к системе одновременно* - фантазии. Такого значения никто и близко не вкладывает. "with" соответствует либо творительному падежу без предлога, либо родительному с предлогом "с".

Comment: ***Творительный с предлогом*** возможен - да и то с оговорками - разве что в значении "делать совмеcтно с чем/чем" (типа ходил на медведя с рогатиной - bear hunting with a boar) - но это явно не наш случай

Answer (score 1):

Правильно (в рамках привычного профжаргона) -

***С одного и того же аккаунта четверо пользователей не могут получить доступ к системе одновременно.***

У айтишников с давних пор- а через тих теперь уже у любого мало-мальки приобщившегося к цивилизации человека - куда-либо входят или выходят именно "с" (чего?).
Сравните: "С какого телефона/номера ты мне звонил?".

Возможно, кто-то возразит, что **в аккаунт**-де входят, а уж из него - в систему, но это ошибочное представление.  На самом деле все не так. **"С"** здесь означает "с помощью чего", "посредством чего".

> 7. кого-чего, кем-чем. Указывает на средство, способ, характер и т.п. осуществления > действия. Кормить ребёнка с ложечки. Пить с блюдечка.
>    Сидеть у реки с удочкой. Сесть с ногами на диван. Пустить с аукциона.
>    Продавать с рук. Рубить с плеча. Ударить с размаху. Одеваться со
>    вкусом. Влюбиться с первого взгляда. Смотреть на кого-л. с презрением.
>    Проснуться с головной болью. Идти с песнями. Подняться с трудом.
>    Броситься на кого-л. с кулаками. Мыть с мылом. Послать с курьером.
>    Делать что-л. с удовольствием. Оценивать с юридической точки зрения.
>    Уйти с головой в работу. Перебиваться с хлеба на квас.

(БТС Кузнецова).

Там есть и еще значения, которыми можно обосновать выбор предлога и падежа, до я думаю это точнее всего. Аккаунт - то самое блюдечко, **с которого** в примере из БТС пьют чай.

Все же другие варианты справки исходной фразы выглядят надуманными или сделанными человеком, далеким от понимания технических реалий.

Comment: @JKlen *Как человеку, который 15 лет работает в IT... Я не пытаюсь апеллировать к собственному авторитету* - как человек, без малого полвека занимавшийся тем же, предлагаю не мериться авторитетом, он у меня все равно длиннее. *"Технические реалии"* - ну, например, полгода назад меня на голубом глазу убеждали, что аккаунт и личный кабинет - это одно и то же. Подробности, надеюсь, вам не понадобятся.

Comment: *почему вы считаете, что представление о входе "в аккаунт" является ошибочным*. - потому что смысл рассматриваемого выражения не тот. Написал же в ответе всё подробно. --- А вы, простите, серьезно полагаете, что аккаунт - это что-то типа прихожей, **из которой** потом входят ("получают доступ") в комнату?

Comment: @JKlen *"Личный кабинет" это какое-то сугубо* - Ну спасибо. Утешили. Все дело в том, что стоял вопрос адекватного перевода на английский - ваши рассуждизмы о чисто русском изобретении ну никак не помогли бы. Ибо аккаунт и личный кабинет - это заведомо разные вещи. Аккаунт - запись для хранения информации о допущенных к столику, профиль - это набор значений аккаунта (и не только), а личный кабинет - среда для ввода и изменений каких-то там параметров.

Comment: А пример я этот привел не ради получения вашего высокоценимого мнения, а в ответ на ваше недоумение, что такое технические реалии, в которых не все разбираются. Предлагаю на этом закончить, я свое мнение о вашем ответе высказал, ваша воля - прислушаться или нет. Обсуждать что-то в таком ключе, полагаю, бесполезно.